# Sort by date in Object.keys is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying sort my transaction list by date but sorting is not correct. I'm using firebase.

Input from form when I add date

```
      <input
        className="form-control"
        name="date"
        value={values.date}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        type="date"
        required
        pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"
      />
```

const handleInputChange

```
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
```

and list of transaction with sorting

```
<div>
                {Object.keys(expenses)
                  .sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date)
                  .map((key) => (
                    <div className="single-row-table" key={key}>
                      <div className="table-description">
                        {expenses[key].description}
                      </div>
                      <div className="table-category">
                        {expenses[key].category}
                      </div>
                      <div className="table-date">{expenses[key].date}</div>
                      <div className="table-delete-button">
                        <i
                          class="far fa-trash-alt"
                          onClick={() => {
                            onDelete(key);
                          }}
                        ></i>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  ))}
              </div>
```

I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Is your date an integer? Doing `new Date('your string date').getTime();`

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Note also it would be more performant to do the sorting once only when receive or update data and not do it in `render()`

Comment: `Object.keys(expenses).sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date)` will attempt to sort two *keys* by their `date` field. Keys are either strings or symbols and neither of these has a `date` field. Did you mean `expenses[a].date - expenses[b].date`?